# Where does this dialogue come from & how to surpress it?

Tags: batch-file, firefox, dialog, shutdown

I am running a script that tries to launch a browser (firefox) and load a URL from my home intranet's NAS - in order to close it down. This should run unattended. My first problem was getting the "çertificate not recognised" message from the browser, when I want this to run unattended, so I added an exception. Re-tried and then I got the "User / Password" dialogue. So I found a way to insert the credentials into the URL. That seemed to silence that dialogue, but now I get the following pop up - seemingly from the browser, which remains blank unless I Ok it:
[image]
I'm not sure what's generating it. The browser I guess, but it never does this when I access the URL manually. I tried turning off my Avast security in case it came from there. I tried fiddling with Windows (10) security, but still it persists. Any idea how to do this? Here is the .bat line that initiaties it:

> run, C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
>   https://admin:mypassword@192.168.1.10/get_handler?PAGE=System&OUTER_TAB=tab_shutdown&INNER_TAB=NONE&shutdown_option1=1&command=poweroff&OPERATION=set

It might help to know the NAS responds to http, switching it to https, with it's own local certificate. Anyone any ideas on how to circumvent this? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this question is better asked in [SU] with naming the make of your NAS?

Answer (score 0):

I confirmed that the dialog is indeed coming from Firefox, using Window Spy to click on it when it appeared. No idea why it should happen in response to a script and not to a live operator though: it does rather present the script with the sort of issues documented here.

After trying all sorts of techniques to try to either surpress it or Ok it, I found that nothing native to Windows would do the job. I eventually solved the problem by writing a script for [Autohotkey](https://autohotkey.com), making an executable out of it for convenience, and calling that from my close down .bat file.